# Can't inject mock ApplicationEventPublisher in @MicronautTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, micronaut

I'm actively using ApplicationEventPublisher in my app and the main result of some methods executions is publishing event with ApplicationEventPublisher.

I am using a simple trap for events in the test environment in order to collect events and verify them:

```
@Singleton
public class MessageListenerTestHelper {
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void onEvent(Object event) {
        queue.add(event);
    }

    public Queue getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public <T> Future<T> getEventFromQueue(Class<T> eventClass) {
        CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            Optional eventOpt = queue.stream()
                    .filter(eventClass::isInstance)
                    .findAny();
            if (eventOpt.isPresent()) {
                future.complete((T) eventOpt.get());
            }
        }, 100, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return future;
    }
}
```

But my tests are flaky - its usually fails in github actions, but works at my computer. So I want to fix it by mock `ApplicationEventPublisher`. But `@Replaces` annotation doesn't work. I tried it in the test and in factory available only in test environment, but neither of this is worked.

I am going to refuse to use `@MicronautTest` annotation, and inject mocks manually. But maybe there is another choise?

Comment: "But @Replaces annotation doesn't work" - It isn't clear how you tried to use `@Replaces`.  In general it works.  We use it all the time.  If you can provide some more context or even better, a link to a simple app which demonstrates what you are trying to do, that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, I have the same problem, I can't mock ApplicationEventPublisher into a Micronaut test. May you link an example about how to use it? Otherwise I can open  a new question and show you my code

Comment: @Manuel If you can provide a link to a sample app which demonstrates what you are trying to do, that would make your question easier to address.

Comment: Thank @JeffScottBrown. I created a pastebin page:
https://pastebin.com/u/manse13/1/UEHKfezP

Can you reach the folder? The Idea is that I receive a message into one eventlistener and after a manipulation, I send to another event listener

Comment: @JeffScottBrown seems that class ApplicationEventPublisher doesn't intercepted by micronaut test

Comment: hi @JeffScottBrown any news??

Comment: "hi JeffScottBrown any news??" - @Manuel No, I don't have any news.  If you are willing to create a buildable project and share a link to that, I will be happy to look at it.  If I create a project and put your code in it, there are any number of things that could be different in your project that might be relevant.  A link to a project on GitHub would help folks help you.